# Manipulate :before and :after with javascript

Tags: javascript, css, class

I have a dropdown nav bar (fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tvez5hmn/1/) and snippet below). When a SubItem is clicked, JS function makes an Ajax call (not shown). What I want to achieve is to hide the SubItems list when SubItem is clicked, to avoid the current annoying overlapping.

```js
function GetData(TheClicked,WhichItem) {
 //In the working version, here is an Ajax call;
 document.getElementById("MainContainer").innerHTML = 'SomeTextSomeTextSomeTextSomeText';
}
```

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 background: #fcf8f2;
}
.NavBarContainer {
 position: block;
  clear: both;
 top: 0;
 width: 100%;
 background: #4a535b;
}
.NavBar ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.NavBar ul li {
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 float: left;
}
.NavBar li ul { display: none; }

.NavBar ul li a {
 display: block;
 padding: 0.6rem;
 text-decoration: none;
 white-space: nowrap;
 color: #fffbf4;
 font-size:1.2rem;
 letter-spacing:0.1rem;
 -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
 animation: fadeIn 1s;
}

.NavBar ul li a:hover { 
 background: #2c3e50; 
 -webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s ease-out;
 -moz-transition: background-color 0.5s ease-out;
 -o-transition: background-color 0.5s ease-out;
 transition: background-color 0.5s ease-out;
}
.NavBar li:hover > ul {
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
}

.NavBar li:hover li { float: none; }

.NavBar li:hover a { background: #4a535b; }

.NavBar li:hover li a:hover { background: #2c3e50; }

.NavBar li ul li { border-top: 0; }
.NavBar ul ul ul {
 left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}

.NavBar ul:before,
.NavBar ul:after {
 content: " "; /* 1 */
 display: table; /* 2 */
}
.NavBar ul:after { clear: both; }

.MainContainer {
 background: #fffcf9;
 margin: auto;
 width: 80%;
 border-style:solid;
 border-width:thin;
 border-color:#e2e0d9;
 padding:1rem;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="NavBarContainer" id="NavBarContainer">
<div class="NavBar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Item#1</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="GetData(this,'SubItem_11');">SubItem_11</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="GetData(this,'SubItem_12'); return false;">SubItem_12</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="GetData(this,'SubItem_13'); return false;">SubItem_13</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  <li><a href="#">Item#2</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="GetData(this,'SubItem_21'); return false;">SubItem_21</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="GetData(this,'SubItem_22'); return false;">SubItem_22</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="GetData(this,'SubItem_23'); return false;">SubItem_23</a></li>
      </ul>   
  </li> 
  <li><a href="#">Item#3</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="GetData(this,'SubItem_31');">SubItem_31</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="GetData(this,'SubItem_32');">SubItem_32</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="GetData(this,'SubItem_33');">SubItem_33</a></li>
      </ul>   
  </li>     
  </ul>     
</div>
</div>


<div class="MainContainer" id="MainContainer">...</div>
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: If you click SubItem_22 for example and don't move the mouse away, the response text lies below the dropdown. I want the SubItems list to dissapear onclick (and only appear again if hovering mouse over main menu).

Comment: Well the CSS pseudo-classes do what they do, and you can't affect that with JavaScript. If you want your menu to behave differently, you'll have to do it with JavaScript generally, handling "mouseenter", "mouseleave", etc events and adding/removing classes as necessary.

Comment: I see. I was hoping there was some JS trick to avoid rewriting all the existent css. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to manipulate the :after and :before pseudo elements, you want to hide the UL element. What you can do is hide the UL when the user clicks any link setting `display` to `none` (and don't forget to remove the property afte that).

```
function GetData(TheClicked,WhichItem) {
  parent = TheClicked.parentElement.parentElement; //get the UL
  parent.style.display = 'none'; //hide it

  //In the working version, here is an Ajax call;
  document.getElementById("MainContainer").innerHTML = 'SomeTextSomeTextSomeTextSomeText';

  //remove the display set before
  setTimeout(function(){
    parent.style.removeProperty('display');
  }, 50)
}
```

Note the timeout, if you remove the property without it, the `.NavBar` element doesn't look the `hover` state and the menu popups up again.

A few suggestions:

- don't use Capital letter at the beginning of variables and functions, leave that to javascript classes (use `getData`, `theClicked` and `whichItem`)
- some `click` event callbacks returns false and some don't, read about the `event` object on the callbacks and the correct use of `event.preventDefault()` instead of returning false
- you don't need to pass the text as a parameter, you can get it with `theClicked.innerText` to simplify your code

Comment: I tried both solutions (@arieljoud and @Armel) and both do the job, and I like both. One of you contribute with suggestions, the other with the snippet. Accepting one or another is (for me) just alike, so decision was random. Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to deactivate the pointer events and re-activate it right after the sub-menu is hidden, for example:

```js
function GetData(TheClicked,WhichItem) {
    //In the working version, here is an Ajax call;
    document.getElementById("MainContainer").innerHTML = 'SomeTextSomeTextSomeTextSomeText';
    // The parent ul
    var parent = TheClicked.parentElement.parentElement;
    // De-activate the pointer-events
    parent.style['pointer-events'] = 'none';
    // Re-activate the pointer-events after 100ms
    setTimeout(function() {
        parent.style['pointer-events'] = '';
    }, 100);
}
```

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 background: #fcf8f2;
}
.NavBarContainer {
 position: block;
  clear: both;
 top: 0;
 width: 100%;
 background: #4a535b;
}
.NavBar ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.NavBar ul li {
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 float: left;
}
.NavBar li ul { display: none; }

.NavBar ul li a {
 display: block;
 padding: 0.6rem;
 text-decoration: none;
 white-space: nowrap;
 color: #fffbf4;
 font-size:1.2rem;
 letter-spacing:0.1rem;
 -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
 animation: fadeIn 1s;
}

.NavBar ul li a:hover { 
 background: #2c3e50; 
 -webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s ease-out;
 -moz-transition: background-color 0.5s ease-out;
 -o-transition: background-color 0.5s ease-out;
 transition: background-color 0.5s ease-out;
}
.NavBar li:hover > ul {
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
}

.NavBar li:hover li { float: none; }

.NavBar li:hover a { background: #4a535b; }

.NavBar li:hover li a:hover { background: #2c3e50; }

.NavBar li ul li { border-top: 0; }
.NavBar ul ul ul {
 left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}

.NavBar ul:before,
.NavBar ul:after {
 content: " "; /* 1 */
 display: table; /* 2 */
}
.NavBar ul:after { clear: both; }

.MainContainer {
 background: #fffcf9;
 margin: auto;
 width: 80%;
 border-style:solid;
 border-width:thin;
 border-color:#e2e0d9;
 padding:1rem;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="NavBarContainer" id="NavBarContainer">
<div class="NavBar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Item#1</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="GetData(this,'SubItem_11');">SubItem_11</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="GetData(this,'SubItem_12'); return false;">SubItem_12</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="GetData(this,'SubItem_13'); return false;">SubItem_13</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  <li><a href="#">Item#2</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="GetData(this,'SubItem_21'); return false;">SubItem_21</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="GetData(this,'SubItem_22'); return false;">SubItem_22</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="GetData(this,'SubItem_23'); return false;">SubItem_23</a></li>
      </ul>   
  </li> 
  <li><a href="#">Item#3</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="GetData(this,'SubItem_31');">SubItem_31</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="GetData(this,'SubItem_32');">SubItem_32</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="GetData(this,'SubItem_33');">SubItem_33</a></li>
      </ul>   
  </li>     
  </ul>     
</div>
</div>


<div class="MainContainer" id="MainContainer">...</div>
```

Comment: I tried both solutions (@arieljoud and @Armel) and both do the job, and I like both. One of you contribute with suggestions, the other with the snippet. Accepting one or another is (for me) just alike, so decision was random. Gracias!